# Is there a concept of "Satan" in Hinduism?

Tags: asuras, evil

Is there a concept of `Satan` in Hinduism?. If so just cite the references.

How do the Asuras of the Puranas compare to this concept of evil entities?

Comment: Limit your question to a single point. Currently, you are asking two different topics. Satan concept in Hinduism is already asked and answered . [Does the concept of Evil Spirits occur in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/147/5212)

Comment: Satan is there in Hinduism?